# Why do I get a HTTP Error 403 when making a request to the Giphy API?

Tags: python, flask, urllib2, pythonanywhere, giphy-api

I am using urllib2 to make requests to the Giphy API and I am using the public API key. The exact same code is working fine on Google App Engine, but when I try executing it with Pythonanywhere I get "HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden". I already tried adding some headers.

```
WEBHOOK_URL = 'https://url/webhook'
GIPHY_API_KEY = 'xxx'
BOT_TOKEN = 'xxx'
GIPHY_HOST = "http://api.giphy.com"

app = Flask(__name__)
bot = telegram.Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook_handler():
    if request.method == "POST":
        update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True))
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        text = update.message.text.encode('utf-8')

        if text:
            values = text.split(" ", 1)
            command = values[0].lower()

            if command == '/gif':
                if len(values) > 1:
                    endpoint = GIPHY_HOST + '/v1/gifs/random'
                    data = {
                        "api_key": GIPHY_API_KEY,
                        "tag": values[1],
                    }
                    endpoint = endpoint + '?' + urllib.urlencode(data)
                    req = urllib2.Request(endpoint)
                    resp= urllib2.urlopen(req)
                    image_url = json.loads(resp.read())["data"]["image_url"]
                    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=image_url)
    return 'ok'

@app.route('/set_webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def set_webhook():
    bot.setWebhook(WEBHOOK_URL)
    return "webhook set"


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '.'


2015-09-08 23:20:25,273 :Exception on /webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jannikko2/untitled/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jannikko2/untitled/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/jannikko2/untitled/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jannikko2/untitled/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jannikko2/untitled/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/jannikko2/untitled/main.py", line 42, in webhook_handler
    resp= urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Please show us your code! (You should replace your keys with a dummy.)

Comment: Also, use `requests` if you can

Comment: possible duplicate of [open url from pythonanywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597390/open-url-from-pythonanywhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you have a free account and they only have access to a whitelist of sites. If you'd like us to add a site to the whitelist, send a request to support@pythonanywhere.com or use the feedback form. Include a link to the API docs in the request.